# Integrating $F=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$ to get $E=T+V$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, potential, potential-energy

I'm, trying to integrate

$$
m\ddot{r} = -\frac{\partial V(r)}{\partial r}
$$

To arrive at $E=T+V$.

I'm capable of getting to

$$
\frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2 + \text{constant} = -V +\text{constant}
\\
\frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2 + V = \text{constant}
\\
T+V = \text{constant}
$$

but I'm not sure what conservation law, boundary condition, etc. I need to use to call the constant $E$.

Any tips?

Comment: Where is the angular motion?

Comment: @Qmechanic of course! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can call the constant whatever you'd like;$$T+V=E$$$$T+V=E^2$$$$T+V+2\,\text{Joules}=E$$ are all valid. However if you want to use that constant for the mechanical energy of that system,$$E=T+V$$ must be used, by most definitions of mechanical energy.